# Add days and time to Calender object

Tags: java

I am trying to add X number of days (from 1 to 180 days) to an Calender object, then build a new timestamp to save in DB consisting of new generated date + (time = time now). the code below is what I've done so far, so can someone please help me with any code sample required to do the remaining part of generating the timestamp with new generated date + (time = time now)?

This is the code I am using so far:

```
Date todayDate = new Date();        
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

switch(daysToAdd){
case 1:
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);             
break;
case 2:
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 14);
break;
case 3:
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 21);
break;              
case 4:
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
break;
case 5:
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 60);
break;              
case 6:
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 90);
break;              
case 7:
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 180);
break;                              
default: c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
}

Date enddate = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate timestamp based on your original date object. Next, you would need to get a reference to a Calendar instance which you are correctly using to do the manipulation/addition.

```
Date todayDate = new Date();
Timestamp original = new Timestamp(todayDate.getTime());
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.setTimeInMillis(original.getTime());
```

After your additions and switch/case, you can instantiate a new Timestamp instance to validate your additions:

```
Timestamp later = new Timestamp(c.getTime().getTime());
```

Assuming you can pass the number of days as a method parameter, here is the your modified working code assuming a hardcoded number of days value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date todayDate = new Date();
        Timestamp original = new Timestamp(todayDate.getTime());
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        System.out.println("Old time : " + original.toString());

        c.setTimeInMillis(original.getTime());

        int daysToAdd = 5;

        switch (daysToAdd) {
        case 1:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
            break;
        case 2:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 14);
            break;
        case 3:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 21);
            break;
        case 4:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
            break;
        case 5:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 60);
            break;
        case 6:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 90);
            break;
        case 7:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 180);
            break;
        default:
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
        }

        Timestamp later = new Timestamp(c.getTime().getTime());
        System.out.println("New time : " + later.toString());
    }
```

The output to the above code is (added 60 days with option 5):

```
Old time : 2013-12-29 18:30:41.541
New Date : 2014-02-27 18:30:41.541
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`TimeStamp(long time)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28long%29)  Constructor

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(enddate.getTime());
```

or even directly from calander instance

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().plusDays( yourNumber ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Convert to java.util.Date if necessary.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Convert to java.sql.Date for use with JDBC.

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date( dateTime.getMillis() );
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `getTime()` method of the Calendar object we can return Date Object.

but there is no method for returning Timestamp object directly from Calendar

You can use the `Timestamp` Constructor

```
Timestamp enddate = new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
```